# Fill Column using a for loop from multiple dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, for-loop, append

I have multiple dictionaries and I'm trying to append them into one dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
dict1 = {'A': '1', 'B': [{'att1': 'value1', 'att2': 'value2'}]}
dict2 = {'A': '2', 'B': [{'att1': 'value3', 'att2': 'value4'}]}
df = pd.DataFrame()
dict = [dict1, dict2]
df['A'] = []
for i in range(0, 2):
    df = df.append(dict[i]['B'])
    df['A'] = (dict[i]['A'])
```

This gives

```
   A    att1    att2
0  2  value1  value2
0  2  value3  value4
```

However I'd want

```
   A    att1    att2
0  1  value1  value2
0  2  value3  value4
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pd.concat

```
(
    pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(dict1), pd.DataFrame(dict2)])
    .pipe(lambda x: pd.concat([x,x.B.apply(pd.Series)],1))
    .drop('B',1)
)

    A   att1    att2
0   1   value1  value2
0   2   value3  value4
```

Comment: If I use a for loop on this, it would only give dict[1]. my ultimate goal is to write a for loop to combine as many dictionaries.

Comment: I used the append function with the for loop and it gave what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Build the row you want to append:

```
for i in range(0, 2):
    row = dict[i]['B']
    row[0].update({'A': dict[i]['A']})
    df = df.append(row)
    print(df)
```

Output:

```
   A    att1    att2
0  1  value1  value2

   A    att1    att2
0  1  value1  value2
0  2  value3  value4
```

This will likely be smoother for you if you research how to build an entire data frame from a dict (or JSON object).  I've solved only the immediate problem.

Answer (score 1):

u can use [json normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```
from pandas import json_normalize
def normalize(mapping):
    return json_normalize(mapping, 'B', 'A')

pd.concat((normalize(dict1),normalize(dict2)))
    att1    att2    A
0   value1  value2  1
0   value3  value4  2
```

Comment: This only seems to work on two dictionaries.. my ultimate goal is to write a for loop to combine as many dictionaries...

Answer (score 0):

An elegant solution is possible based on `pd.json_normalize`, but one
obstacle in this way is that `B` key in your both dictionaries contain
a **list** with a single element, whereas they should contain just
this element.

To overcome this obstacle, run a list comprehension, creating a list of
dictionaries, with a nested dictionary comprehension converting such a list
into an underlying element:

```
dct = [ { k: v[0] if isinstance(v, list) else v for k, v in d.items()}
    for d in [dict1, dict2]]
```

The result is:

```
[{'A': '1', 'B': {'att1': 'value1', 'att2': 'value2'}},
 {'A': '2', 'B': {'att1': 'value3', 'att2': 'value4'}}]
```

Then you can call `df = pd.json_normalize(dct)`, getting:

```
   A  B.att1  B.att2
0  1  value1  value2
1  2  value3  value4
```

And the only thing remaining to be done is to rename both *B.…* columns:

```
df.rename(columns={'B.att1' : 'att1', 'B.att2' : 'att2'}, inplace=True)
```

Now you have just what you want, i.e.:

```
   A    att1    att2
0  1  value1  value2
1  2  value3  value4
```

Caution: `pd.json_normalize` appeared in *Pandas* version *1.0*.
Earlier this method was "hidden" in `pandas.io.json` package.

Answer (score 0):

Moving from Allen's, I ended up getting what I need by the following:

```
dict1 = {'A': '1', 'B': [{'att1': 'value1', 'att2': 'value2'}]}
dict2 = {'A': '2', 'B': [{'att1': 'value3', 'att2': 'value4'}]}
dict = [dict1, dict2]

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['A'] = []
for i in range(0, 2):
    df = df.append(pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(dict[i])]).pipe(lambda x: pd.concat([x, x.B.apply(pd.Series)], 1)).drop('B', 1))
print(df)
```

Gives

```
   A    att1    att2
0  1  value1  value2
0  2  value3  value4
```